# Which one to use? Vector or List

Tags: list, generics, data-structures, vector, stl

I have to store 10 elements of type card (user defined class). I cannot decide whether to go with vector or list. Following are the operations I would be performing on the structure:

1. Appending or Inserting at the end of the structure
   (better to go with vector).
2. Ramdom access(element to be accessed can be at end, begining or any position in the structure) (again vector is a better choice).
3. To delete the random accessed element i.e. Erasing an element from begining or end or any position
   (Vector only good for end positions, elsewhere list preferred).
4. Move element from one position to other such that the element is not swapped with the element at desired position but it gets
   inserted within (List are much better here).
5. To move more than one elements in the same manner as point 4.
   (Again I would prefer list)

So can you please guide me which one to pick.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Are you storing pointers in the vector/list? If not, what is the sizeof the card class? Modern processors are extremely good with small to medium sized arrays. And vectors eliminate the pointer operations of lists.

Comment: No, I am not storing pointers.
And the size of the class is 40.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have done your research on vector and list, as you can see there are some conflicting requirements. One other thing to consider is perhaps the frequent of those operations. I.e how often are you expecting to be inserting or deleting from the middle of the collection. Another consideration is the size of the collection, 10 elements is **a very small** collection so copying 10 elements around isn't a big deal unless you are doing it very frequently. My default choice would be vector, but you can profile both to see which one performs better.

Comment: Well, how to profile them?
For just 10 values they both are going to be executed almost in the same time?

Comment: You can try doing it in a loop of say a million iterations. That should show some difference.

Comment: Well, If 1000 iterations will show the significant difference, that means for only 10 elements no significant change is there. Thus using any of them will hardly make any difference.

Comment: I suppose list would be better option for me as: the top three operations I have mentioned in the question are going to be operated 10 times each i.e. 30 total operations, which is fixed. But the last two operations are going to be executed as many times as the user wants. It can be from 0 to any number of times the user wishes. And in both of the last cases list are better choice. So going to implement a list.